# www.server.com/*.aspx returns server error rather than custom error

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I have updated my customerr folder to have a common error page which will be displayed for any sort of error.

**www.server.com/wrongone**

takes to me to the custom error page. -> Working fine

**www.server.com/correctone/wrongone.aspx** -> This is handled at application level, so I have no problem with this.

But when I hit **www.server.com/wrongone.aspx**,

It displays Server error. -> I dont want to display server error

What should I do ( at IIS Level) to redirect this to custom error page?

Answer (score 0):

It depend on what status did you get. To set custom error page for .aspx file, you should set .NET error page `<customError>` instead of error page.

You could find it in IIS manager->site node->.NET error page and you need to add rule for your status code/error page.  When you hit the error status code, the page will be redirected to your custom error page. If your status code is 500, then custom page would fail in some case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831398(v%3Dws.11)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I have my own html page (common.html) under custerr directory. In "Error Pages" in IIS, I have mapped all the status codes to common.html.

Comment: Also, I have mapped my build folder to an application (correctone) under a website. ex: www.server.com/correctone/Pages/Signin.aspx. Any wrong text after "www.server.com/correctone/" is being handled by the asp.net application. But since the www.server.com/wrongone/something.aspx is not in asp.net scope, It throws 

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. ...

I think the file extension (.aspx) is registered in Handler Mapping, I see the above error. If I replace .aspx with xyz, it correctly redirecting to the IIS custom error page.